# How can I replace the syntax "wait on a" in vhdl with equivalent syntax that won't initiate an infinite loop and is synthesizable on quartus?

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga, quartus

I am working on a single cycle processor using vhdl. I was trying to solve bugs in the code but eventually we were trapped in two situations in the instruction memory and data memory(in imem & dmem):

1. there is a part in the code ( “wait on a”) that can’t be synthesized on quarus and also a problem with loops that make the code loop infinitely on quartus
2. we tried to replace loops and (wait on a) with (process(a)) but also we have a problem that there can’t be a process inside another process.

How can I solve these bugs?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all; use STD.TEXTIO.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_arith.all;

entity imem is -- instruction memory
port(a: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
   rd: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0));
end;

architecture behave of imem is -- instruction memory
type ramtype is array (63 downto 0) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);

begin
process is
  file mem_file: TEXT;
  variable L: line;
  variable ch: character;
  variable i, index, result: integer;
  --type ramtype is array (63 downto 0) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
  variable mem: ramtype;
begin
  -- initialize memory from file
  for i in 0 to 63 loop -- set all contents low
    mem(i) := (others => '0');
  end loop;
  index := 0;
  FILE_OPEN(mem_file, "memfile.dat", READ_MODE);
  while not endfile(mem_file) loop
    readline(mem_file, L);
    result := 0;
    for i in 1 to 8 loop
    read(L, ch);
      if '0' <= ch and ch <= '9' then
        result := character'pos(ch) - character'pos('0');
      elsif 'a' <= ch and ch <= 'f' then
        result := character'pos(ch) - character'pos('a') + 10;
      elsif 'A' <= ch and ch <= 'F' then
        result := character'pos(ch) - character'pos('A') + 10;
      else report "Formaterror on line " & integer'image(index)
        severity error;
      end if;
      mem(index)(35-i*4 downto 32-i*4) :=conv_std_logic_vector(result,4);
    end loop;
    index := index + 1;
  end loop;
  -- read memory
  loop 
    rd <= mem(conv_integer(unsigned(a(7 downto 2))));
    wait on a;
  end loop;
end process;
end;
```

Comment: As reported by @Tricky, I overlooked that you're using Quartus. As far was we both know, Quartus does not support reading files in initializer functions. The whole package `textio` for file I/O is not supported / ignored. You need to use the Altera MegaFunction primitives from VHDL library `altera_mf` called `altsyncram` to represent a RAM or ROM. The [PoC-Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC) has an implementation [here](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/mem/ocram/altera/ocram_sp_altera.vhdl?ts=2).

Answer (score 4):

As reported by @Tricky, I overlooked that you're using [quartus](/questions/tagged/quartus). As far was we both know, Quartus does not support reading files in initializer functions. The whole package `textio` for file I/O is not supported / ignored. You need to use the Altera Mega Function primitives from VHDL library `altera_mf` called `altsyncram` to represent a RAM or ROM. The PoC-Library has an implementation here.

`altsyncram` example for a single-port RAM:

```
library altera_mf;
use     altera_mf.all;

mem : altsyncram
    generic map (
        address_aclr_a         => "NONE",
        indata_aclr_a          => "NONE",
        init_file              => INIT_FILE,
        intended_device_family => getAlteraDeviceName(DEVICE),
        lpm_hint               => "ENABLE_RUNTIME_MOD = NO",
        lpm_type               => "altsyncram",
        numwords_a             => DEPTH,
        operation_mode         => "SINGLE_PORT",
        outdata_aclr_a         => "NONE",
        outdata_reg_a          => "UNREGISTERED",
        power_up_uninitialized => "FALSE",
        widthad_a              => A_BITS,
        width_a                => D_BITS,
        width_byteena_a        => 1,
        wrcontrol_aclr_a       => "NONE"
    )
    port map (
        clocken0   => ce,
        wren_a     => we,
        clock0     => clk,
        address_a  => a_sl,
        data_a     => d,
        q_a        => q
    );
```

Source: https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/mem/ocram/altera/ocram_sp_altera.vhdl?ts=2

---

**Original answer:**
You need to put your RAM initializing code into a function, which is returning the initial values for your RAM. In the function, you read the external file and convert each line to a memory value.

Here are some snippets to get you onto the right way:

```
architecture a of e is
  type ram_type is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

  function initialize(
    constant file_name : string;
    constant size      : positive
  ) return ram_type is
    file mem_file   : text;
    variable result : ram_type(0 to size - 1);
  begin
    file_open(mem_file, file_name, READ_MODE);

    while not endfile(mem_file) loop
      -- ... read and convert content
    end loop;

    file_close(mem_file);

    return result;
  end function;

  signal mem : ram_type := initialize("memfile.dat", 64);

begin
  process(a)
  begin
    rd <= mem(to_integer(unsigned(a(7 downto 2))));
  end process;
```

**More hints:**

- Normally reading an instruction memory (BlockRAM) is a clocked process. Currently you are reading asynchronously on every address change.
- A `wait on` statement is equivalent to a process with a sensitivity list.
- You should close opened files.
- Don't use package `STD_LOGIC_arith`, use `numeric_std` instead.

Comment: There is an issue here - the OP says they are using Quartus, and while the code is valid, Quartus does not support textio for memory initialisation during synthesis. @AhmedAbdelkarim will need to use a .mif file for this (but the above code is required for simulation)

Comment: @Tricky You are right, I overlooked the "Quartus" hint. Is the new Quartus from Intel still as restrictive on this silly feature request? On one side they support generic types in entities (VHDL-2008 feature normally only supported in simulators) and on the user side they refuse to support textio ...

Comment: I added the `altera_mf.altsyncram` example, which can read *memory initialization files* (MIF) files.